# Pandas: Find the maximum range in all the columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new very new to programming, so hopefully I'll ask my question clearly and perhaps you can guide me to the answer.

I have a dataframe "x", where the index represents the week of the year, and each column represents a numerical value of a city. I'm attempting to find the column that has the maximum range (ie: maximum value - minimum value). I can imagine this will need a loop to find the maximum and minimum of each column, store this as an object (or as a new row at the bottom perhaps?), and then find the max in that object (or row).

The dataframe looks like this:

```
        City1 City2 ... CityN 
week
1
2
3
4
...
53
```

Feedback on etiquette or wording is also appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you want to find the column with the maximum value of `max(col)-min(col)`?

Comment: Yes. range as in: range(col_i) = max(col_i) - min(col_i).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like `(df.max() - df.min()).idxmax()` should get you a maximum column:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,4)), index=pd.Series(range(1,6), name="week"), columns=["City{}".format(i) for i in range(1,5)])
>>> df
         City1     City2     City3     City4
week                                        
1     0.908549  0.496167  0.220340  0.464060
2     0.429330  0.770133  0.824774  0.155694
3     0.893270  0.980108  0.574897  0.378443
4     0.982410  0.796103  0.080877  0.416432
5     0.444416  0.667695  0.459362  0.898792
>>> df.max() - df.min()
City1    0.553080
City2    0.483941
City3    0.743898
City4    0.743098
dtype: float64
>>> (df.max() - df.min()).idxmax()
'City3'
>>> df[(df.max() - df.min()).idxmax()]
week
1       0.220340
2       0.824774
3       0.574897
4       0.080877
5       0.459362
Name: City3, dtype: float64
```

If there might be more than one column at maximum range, you'll probably want something like

```
>>> col_ranges = df.max() - df.min()
>>> df.loc[:,col_ranges == col_ranges.max()]
         City3
week          
1     0.220340
2     0.824774
3     0.574897
4     0.080877
5     0.459362
```

instead.